# Dynamically AddHandler

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, addhandler

I have a large number of buttons on a form (144 buttons). The names of each button is a combination of different factors.

I need them to all do the same thing when pressed. I have this event under a Private Sub called "ClickButton".

I want to use a loop, to AddHandler each button to the "ClickButton" event.

First however, I need to address each button. I do this by constructing their name dynamically in a loop.

```
Dim PeriodRoomID As New Button
Dim cntrl() As Control    

For Each Row In dsAllRooms.Tables("sqlAllRooms").Rows
            For Count = 1 To 13
                RoomID = Row.Item(0)
'This is where the name of each room is dynamically created. 
'It is stored in PeriodRoomID.name
                PeriodRoomID.Name = "R02" & RoomID.PadLeft(3, "0"c) & Count
                cntrl = Me.Controls.Find(PeriodRoomID.Name, True)
                AddHandler cntrl(0).Click, AddressOf ClickButton
            Next
        Next
```

The problem is nothing happens. The AddHandler doesn't work. However, if I simply write one of the names of the buttons;

```
AddHandler R020011, AddressOf ClickButton
```

Then it does work. Something is going wrong at Me.Controls.Find. It doesn't seem to be able to find any button under that name which is strange because I use the same code in other sections and it finds the button.

Comment: At what point in the page lifecycle is this routine running? At what point are you creating the buttons?

Comment: Are there other buttons in the same form? In other words, would setting the handler for all of the buttons on the form work for you?

Comment: @jfmags The buttons are not dynamically created, they are created with the form.

Comment: @svick There are other buttons unfortunately :(

Comment: Why dont you just specify the OnClick="ClickButton" in the design view then for each button?

Comment: @jfmags That is so redundant. I would have to do that for 144 buttons.

Comment: Why is PeriodicRoomID a button instance when it's just used as a string var to pass to find() function? Are your form created buttons named already, or are you trying to achieve that in that loop?

Comment: Add these debugging statements prior to the `AddHandler` line: `Debug.Assert(cntrl.Length=1) : Debug.Assert(cntrl(0).Name=PeriodRoomId.Name)` and confirm they don't fail when you run this form (in a Debug configuration).

Answer (score 1):

You define `Dim PeriodRoomID As New Button` out of `for` statement so each time you set name 
you set it to the same button `PeriodRoomID` so you don't need this button and `cntrl` neither at all just :

```
For Each Row In dsAllRooms.Tables("sqlAllRooms").Rows
            For Count = 1 To 13
                RoomID = Row.Item(0)
                'This is where the name of each room is dynamically created.   
                dim Ctrls = Me.Controls.Find("R02" & RoomID.PadLeft(3, "0"c) & CStr(Count), True)
                If (Ctrls.Count > 0) Then
                   AddHandler Ctrls(0).Click, AddressOf ClickButton
                End If
            Next
Next
```